# Assign multiple IP addresses to existing virtual machines access web server

Tags: azure, iis, virtual-machine, nic, azure-public-ip

We have Azure Virtual Machine (VM) has one network interface (NIC) attached to it one NIC and have one or more static public IP associated it.

Reasons for Attaching Multiple static Public IPS

- Hosting multiple websites or services with different IP addresses on a single server
- Hosting the Wildcard Entry domains on a single server

Problem with the second IP we cont access the IIS server in Azure Virtual Machine (VM)

How to attach the second IP to access the IIS in VM?

Comment: Have you checked azure docs -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-multiple-ip-addresses-portal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To connect and sign in to a VM you created with multiple private IP addresses. You must **manually add all the private IP addresses** (including the primary) that you added to the VM. You can get the detailed steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-multiple-ip-addresses-portal#os-config).

**Main steps:**

1. Type `ncpa.cpl` in the CMD to pen the Network connections window and add the following values manually.
   [image]
2. Add all the private IP addresses to that VM **Advanced TCP/IP settings**.
   [image]
3. Save it then restart your Azure VM, reestablish a RDP connection, then you can see the valid private IP addresses in the `ipconfig/all`.
   [image]

Then, you should access your websites via the secondary public IP address.

Comment: enabled wildcard entry domain but accessing WCF services hosted in IIS getting an issue The protocol binding '*:80:*.xxx.com' is not valid for 'http'.  This might be because the port number is out of range. @nancy xiong

Comment: I think you can use the same port 80 or 443 for your different websites with a each different private IP address in the binding of protocol type HTTP,HTTPS. For the multiple SSL sites binding, you can refer to [this](https://www.azurecorner.com/hosting-multiple-ssl-sites-in-azure-vms/)